# Apparent counter example to Stoke's theorem?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I think I found an apparent contradiction to Stoke's theorem with this 2-differential form

$M= \overline{B^{2}}- \{ 0 \}$,

$\partial M = S^1$,

$$\omega = \frac{x~dy-y~dx}{x^2+y^2}$$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ and then pullbacked to  $ \overline{B^{2}}- \{ 0 \}$

$d \omega = 0$ So that by Stoke's Theorem

$$ \int\limits_{\partial M} \omega = \int\limits_{M}  d \omega = 0 $$

But direct calculation shows that $\int\limits_{S^1} \omega \neq 0 $

Comment: Stokes's theorem, to my knowledge, only applies to compact manifolds with boundary (or compactly supported forms).

Comment: Thicken the deleted point to an open disk so that $M$ becomes a manifold with boundary. Then $M$ is an annulus centered at the origin and $\omega = d\theta$ in the usual polar coordinates, so Stokes' theorem holds. The compactness of $M$--- or something similar, like requiring $\omega$ to have compact support--- is necessary. (Well, there are extensions of Stokes' theorem for noncompact manifolds, but that's a separate topic.)

Comment: Though not a counter example to Stokes, you did find an interesting, famous and fundamental example: $$\int_{\partial M}\omega$$ is the imaginary part of $$\int_{\partial M}\frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi \textrm{i}$$ where $M$ is identified with the closed unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The same phenomenon is seen in complex variables: $\displaystyle\int_C\frac{dz}z=0$ if $C$ is a simple closed curve that is the boundary of a subset of the domain of $z\mapsto1/z$.  But if $C$ is any circle centered at $0$ or any reasonable curve that winds once counterclockwise around $0$, then the integral is $2\pi i$.  And if $z=x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$, then $\operatorname{Im}(dz/z) = \operatorname{Im}\Big((dx+i\,dy)/(x+iy)\Big)=(x\,dy-y\,dx)/(x^2+y^2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your $M$ is not compact, and $\omega$ is not compactly supported. So you have not contradicted Stokes's theorem.

Comment: oh I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Congratulation! You found something which leads to idea of closed but not exact forms and cohomology groups.

To see the problem take $M= \overline{B^2(1)} \setminus B^2(\epsilon)$. Than $\partial M = S^1(1) - S^1(\epsilon)$. Now the Stokes theorems says:
$$
\int_{S^1(1)} \omega - \int_{S^1(\epsilon)} \omega = \int_M d\omega
$$
You might think that integral $\int_{S^1(\epsilon)} \omega$ goes to zero as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, but that is not true. In fact that integral does not depend on $\epsilon$, so you cannot omit it if $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: So that Stokes applied in that manifold tells you that $\int_{S^1(1)} \omega = \int_{S^1(\epsilon)} \omega$ for every $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yup, exactly...

Comment: Cool thanks! :)

Comment: Plus did you take course in complex analysis? Your closed form is exactly $\frac1{z}$ for which is troublesome to find anti-derivative on whole $\mathbb{C}$.